# Confused about how to order my firewalld rules

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, centos7, firewalld

I had firewalld rules that opened a port, but the port was still closed.

I changed up the order of my rules and it started working- dont understand why.

This is what I had before:

```
cat /etc/firewalld/direct.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>

  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="INPUT">-p ipv4-icmp -m comment --comment ipv4_icmp -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv6" chain="INPUT">-p ipv6-icmp -m comment --comment ipv6_icmp -j ACCEPT</rule>

  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="INPUT">-p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -m comment --comment 'Allow SSH' -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv6" chain="INPUT">-p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -m comment --comment 'Allow SSH' -j ACCEPT</rule>

  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="INPUT">-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment established -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv6" chain="INPUT">-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment established -j ACCEPT</rule>

  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="INPUT">-p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 5000:5200 -m comment --comment 'my app' -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv6" chain="INPUT">-p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 5000:5200 -m comment --comment 'my app' -j ACCEPT</rule>

</direct>
```

Now ports 5000-5200 were not open and I could not access them

Then I changed the order to this and it started working:

```
cat /etc/firewalld/direct.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>
  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="INPUT">-p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 5000:5200 -m comment --comment 'my app' -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv6" chain="INPUT">-p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 5000:5200 -m comment --comment 'my app' -j ACCEPT</rule>

  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="INPUT">-p ipv4-icmp -m comment --comment ipv4_icmp -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv6" chain="INPUT">-p ipv6-icmp -m comment --comment ipv6_icmp -j ACCEPT</rule>

  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="INPUT">-p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -m comment --comment 'Allow SSH' -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv6" chain="INPUT">-p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -m comment --comment 'Allow SSH' -j ACCEPT</rule>

  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="INPUT">-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment established -j ACCEPT</rule>
  <rule priority="50" table="filter" ipv="ipv6" chain="INPUT">-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment established -j ACCEPT</rule>

</direct>
```

Why it do dat?

Answer (score 0):

You only have ACCEPT rules, so they order should not make any difference. Rather, have you restarted/reloaded `firewalld`? In this case, it is possible that your previous rules where marked as permanent (so they were saved to disk) but not as runtime (so they where not currently applied).

Comment: I thought that it wouldn't matter but it seemed to. Restarted but that didn't work, it only worked when I changed the order- and then restarted. But I never did a reload so maybe modifying the file forces a service reload?